# Redirect to all requests to folder and https?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, bolt-cms

I am using bolt-cms with htaccess to redirect the root of the URL to the /public folder. Now I need to redirect http to https. How can I concatenate these two rules?

Here's my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mecanalisis.com.ar%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Well, you just insert the http to https redirection before the first rule you currently have. Don't try to mix that with other rules, that's not worth the effort. Each client gets redirected only a single time from http to https.

Comment: I tried that, but it just redirects to https. It does not 'redirect' to the /public folder.
Only the first rule works.

Comment: The first rule redirecting to http works in the first step. That redirects the browser to the new https URL. Then, in a next step, when the browser sends the next request to the new https URL, then the second rule gets applied.